# PHP Passing ID in URL not displaying on page

Tags: php, url

Passing a PlayerID from a Search Results page to the View Stats page...nothing appears on the Stats page.  The ID is in the URL when hovered.  I'm also getting different results when selecting different IDs.  For example 81 will show a cached page and 98 show a blank page.  All caching is disabled.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "pla", "D", "playma");

    if ($link->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: ". $link->connect_error);
    }

    $ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['id']);

    echo "ID is" . $_GET['$ID'];
    //check to see if the ID is passing via URL
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE PlayerID=$ID";
    $result= mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Bad query: $sql");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>  
<html>
<head>
<title>View Player Stats</title>    
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello world</h1>
<h1><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></h1> 
</body>    
</html> 
<?php     
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: "Nothing" means there is no "ID is" either?

Comment: `$_GET['$ID']` is probably not correct. Most likely you want `$_GET[$ID]`

Comment: id=83 is showing in the URL.  Once the link is clicked, the next Stats page is blank.

Comment: The abbreviated URL once clicked from the Search Results page:  http://.../ViewPlayerStats.php?id=98

Comment: Caching issue was with Bluehost...a CDN setting they had to disable as I required no caching for my site.